# Ignoring CalledProcessError

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I am using the `subprocess` module and `check_output()` to create a virtual shell in my Python script, and it works fine for commands that return a zero exit status, however for ones that don't it returns an exception without printing the error that would have been displayed in the output on a normal shell.

For instance, I would expect something to work like this:

```
>>> shell('cat non-existing-file')
cat: non-existing-file: No such file or directory
```

But instead, this happens:

```
>>> shell('cat non-existing-file')
CalledProcessError: Command 'cat non-existing-file' returned non-zero exit status 1 (file "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output)
```

Even though I could remove the Python exception message using `try` and `except`, I still want the `cat: non-existing-file: No such file or directory` to display to the user.

How would I go about doing this?

`shell()`:

```
def shell(command):
    output   = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    finished = output.split('\n')

    for line in finished:
      print line
    return
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
def shell(command):
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    except Exception, e:
        output = str(e.output)
    finished = output.split('\n')
    for line in finished:
        print line
    return
```

Comment: How would I convert the Popen object to a string? It's not working here with `str()`: `<subprocess.Popen object at 0x12a4f90>`

Comment: You can use the __str__() method. For example output.__str__()

Comment: Hm.. did you try the code I just edited in the initial answer?

Comment: Yeah. It seems to actually print the expected output on the terminal where the script is running from, but for where I set it to print (it doesn't actually print, it uses another function for an IRC bot to talk in a channel) it displays the `<subprocess.Popen object at 0x12a4f90>`. Not sure what to do about that.

Comment: UPDATE: even though the previous code worked, the try-except version may be more to your liking, as it does not give the <subprocess.Popen ... > message

Comment: Well, now the output it gives is `Command 'cat nope' returned non-zero exit status 1`, I'd like the error the shell would have given instead of the Python exception message.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15493/discussion-between-smang-and-user1447941)

Comment: python 3, I replace exception capture code: "except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:"  and it works

Comment: There should be an option in subprocess to ignore errors like this.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 3.5+, you can run it with `check=False`:

```
subprocess.run("exit 1", shell=True, check=False)
```

> If check is true, and the process exits with a non-zero exit code, a CalledProcessError exception will be raised. Attributes of that exception hold the arguments, the exit code, and stdout and stderr if they were captured.

For older Python 3 versions, there's different methods for checking vs not checking the call.

To get the output, just pass `capture_output=True` and then get `stdout` value from `CompletedProcess`

Answer (score 0):

How about using `subprocess.run()`

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.run(['cat', 'non-existing-file'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print (output.stderr.decode())
```

Here is the output

```
> python3 file.py
cat: non-existing-file: No such file or directory
```